# How can I mitigate peeling ceiling texture?

Tags: repair

Artex ceiling is peeling away after my brother sprayed bleach mold cleaner on a spot by the window. What would be the best way to deal with it? I know Artex can have asbestos.

Comment: Need a picture. Do you want to remove it all or just repair the patch where it's peeling? To confirm asbestos you'll have to get it tested.

Comment: Anything prior to the mid 80’s probably had asbestos. The texture in a can works I would caution not to tape close to where you are reapplying texture or there will be a tape line forever(from experience).The way we remove the popcorn ceiling texture is to get it wet then it really falls off or can be scraped right into a trash bag. Precautions need to be taken but I have installed hundreds of these ceilings and removed many dozens before asbestosis was a legal issue, and am a great grandfather today but I would observe safety precautions when working with unknown materials treat like asbestos